# dropping all the columns after a matching value without using the index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the below data frame

[image]

and i have a variable as `ID = 1052107168068132864`

How I can filter all the values to drop it after that column and can get the result like below. In a way i want to drop all the column after that Id including it as well.
[image]

and then update the value of `ID` as `1052121282324692992` as the current value.
i want to repeat this in a loop so that every time i get a new data frame the same operation will keep going and if that is the top value then nothing should happen.

I am having two solutions but they only works when index are in serial way :-

```
df.iloc[:df[df.ID == '1052121282324692992'].index.item()]

or 

idx = (df['ID'] == ID).idxmax()
new_df = df.iloc[:idx, :]
```

Comment: Have you considered using your ID column as an index? Or is there a reason why you aren't doing that here?

Comment: Just use `.reset_index(drop=True)`  and you'll have a shiny new index corresponding to the row order?

Comment: thank you both.. I want to make it dynamic and if any tweet is coming then again it should filter like the same... can you help me in creating a kind of loop or something for the same and i want to keep updating the ID everytime

Comment: @ALollz it worked i didnt think of it........i am creating a tweet alert..suppose iam tweeting having words like hate in it then i will send that tweet as email and then store the tweet id and then next time i want to check if thats the same tweet then i dont want to send the notification and if there are tweets with word hate then i dont want to consider the old one and delete it and send the new one as email.......do i make sense? i want to keep repeating that all the time